# convert array of objects to nested array of arrays for building chart

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I have the following array

```
const data = [
      {
        date: "2018-01-01",
        label: "MH",
        qt: 10
      },
      {
        date: "2018-04-01",
        label: "MH",
        qt: 30
      },
      {
        date: "2018-02-01",
        label: "GJ",
        qt: 30
      },
      {
        date: "2018-03-01",
        label: "KL",
        qt: 30
      },
      {
        date: "2018-02-01",
        label: "KL",
        qt: 40
      }
    ]
```

and i want my output to be

```
[
  [date,MH,GJ,KL],
  ['Jan 2018',10,null,null],
  ['Feb 2018',null,30,40],
  ['Mar 2018',null,null,30],
  ['Apr 2018',30,null,null]
]
```

How can i achieve that in an optimize way?
And the date should be sorted in order to.
I tried doing

```
data.sort(function compare(a, b) {
      var dateA = new Date(a.date);
      var dateB = new Date(b.date);
      return dateA - dateB;
    });
    let labelArr = data.map(l => l.label);
    let dateArr = data.map(l => l.date);
    labelArr = _.uniq(labelArr);
    dateArr = _.uniq(dateArr);
    console.log(labelArr, dateArr);

    const outputArr = [];
    dateArr.forEach(d => {
      labelArr.forEach(l => {
        const tempObj = data.filter(r => {
          if (d == r.date && l == r.label) {
            return r;
          }
          else {
            return { date: d, label: l, qt: null }
          }
        })
        outputArr.push(tempObj);
      });
    });
```

but i'm stuck here. What I was thinking is first i'll create the objects for date and label which are not present and add thier qt to null. After that i'll group by date and then insert only the qt to the result

Comment: please add your try.

Comment: do you wan the fixed order of `MH,GJ,KL`?

Comment: @NinaScholz sorry didn't get you

Comment: Can the order in the array of MH, GJ, KL be random?

Comment: @EugenSunic yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried doing this:

```
    data.sort(function compare(a, b) {
      var dateA = new Date(a.date);
      var dateB = new Date(b.date);
      return dateA - dateB;
    });
    let labelArr = data.map(l => l.label);
    let dateArr = data.map(l => l.date);
    labelArr = _.uniq(labelArr);
    dateArr = _.uniq(dateArr);

    const outputArr = [['Date', ...labelArr]];
    dateArr.forEach(d => {
      const o1 = data.filter(e => e.date == d)
      const o2 = o1.reduce((s, a) => {
        s[a.label] = a.qt;
        return s;
      }, {})
      const b1 = []
      labelArr.forEach(l => {
        b1.push(o2[l])
      });
      outputArr.push([moment(d).format('MMM YYYY'), ...b1]);
    });
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

You could take an object for keeping the array for each date and one for keeping track of the indices of the columns.

At the end set all elements to `null` for not set items.

```js
var data = [{ date: "2018-01-01", label: "MH", qt: 10 }, { date: "2018-04-01", label: "MH", qt: 30 }, { date: "2018-02-01", label: "GJ", qt: 30 }, { date: "2018-03-01", label: "KL", qt: 30 }, { date: "2018-02-01", label: "KL", qt: 40 }],
    cols = {},
    rows = {},
    result = data
        .sort(({ date: a }, { date: b }) => a > b || -(a < b))
        .reduce((r, { date, label, qt }) => {
            date = date.slice(0, 7);
            if (!rows[date]) r.push(rows[date] = [date]);
            if (!cols[label]) cols[label] = r[0].push(label) - 1;
            rows[date][cols[label]] = (rows[date][cols[label]] || 0) + qt;
            return r;
        }, [['date']])
        .map((a, _, [{ length }]) => Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => a[i] || null));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's the best solution, but it's a working solution:

```js
const data = [{
    date: "2018-01-01",
    label: "MH",
    qt: 10
  },
  {
    date: "2018-04-01",
    label: "MH",
    qt: 30
  },
  {
    date: "2018-02-01",
    label: "GJ",
    qt: 30
  },
  {
    date: "2018-03-01",
    label: "KL",
    qt: 30
  },
  {
    date: "2018-02-01",
    label: "KL",
    qt: 40
  }
]

function formatData(data) {
  const labels = {};
  const map = {};
  
  data
    .sort((a, b) => a.date < b.date ? -1 : 1)
    .forEach(item => {
      const date = moment(item.date).format('MMM YYYY');
      labels[item.label] = true;
      if (map[date]) {
        map[date][item.label] = item.qt;
      } else {
        map[date] = { [item.label]: item.qt };
      }
    });

  const labelsArr = Object.keys(labels);
  const formattedData = Object.keys(map).map(date => {
    const values = labelsArr.map(label => map[date][label] || null);
    return [date, ...values];
  });
  
  return [['date', ...labelsArr], ...formattedData];
}

const result = formatData(data);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```